# What are the deviations between preprocessors of GCC/CLANG vs MSVC?

Tags: c++, c, macros, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

The following preprocessor macros (the usual suspects: testing on empty argument list and counting number of arguments) run without warnings on gcc/clang but fail on Microsoft VisualC:

```
// IS_EMPTY() returns nothing if the parameter list is empty and a single ',' (comma) otherwise.
// The parameter list can have up to 32 parameters
#define IS_EMPTY(...) IS_EMPTY1(__VA_ARGS__)
#define IS_EMPTY1(...) IS_EMPTY2(DROP_PARAMS  __VA_ARGS__ (,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,EMPTY))
#define IS_EMPTY2(...) IS_EMPTY3(__VA_ARGS__)
#define IS_EMPTY3(f,...) TEST_EMPTY_##f )
#define DROP(...)
#define DROP_PARAMS(...) DROP_PARAMS1(__VA_ARGS__,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,)
#define DROP_PARAMS1(_0,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,__m,...) CATCH_##__m
#define TEST_EMPTY_DROP_PARAMS , DROP(
#define TEST_EMPTY_CATCH_EMPTY DROP(
#define TEST_EMPTY_CATCH_ , DROP(


//--- testcode below ---
#define TEST_EMPTY(...) __VA_ARGS__ : TAKE_2ND(IS_EMPTY(__VA_ARGS__) not,) empty
#define TAKE_2ND(...) TAKE_2ND_(__VA_ARGS__,,)
#define TAKE_2ND_(f,s,...) s

TEST_EMPTY()
TEST_EMPTY(a.b.)
TEST_EMPTY(A)
TEST_EMPTY(())
TEST_EMPTY(int()(more))
TEST_EMPTY((int))
TEST_EMPTY(foo bar)
TEST_EMPTY(*)

#define FOO(x) x
#define BAR
TEST_EMPTY(FOO(BAR))
TEST_EMPTY(1,2)
TEST_EMPTY(1.)
TEST_EMPTY(.1)
TEST_EMPTY(1,)
TEST_EMPTY((int)(float))
TEST_EMPTY(() this)
TEST_EMPTY(() is, () not ()  empty ())
TEST_EMPTY(,notempty)
TEST_EMPTY((),notempty)
TEST_EMPTY((1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,))
```

Output on clang & gcc:

```
: empty
a.b. : not empty
A : not empty
() : not empty
int()(more) : not empty
(int) : not empty
foo bar : not empty
* : not empty



: empty
1,2 : not empty
1. : not empty
.1 : not empty
1, : not empty
(int)(float) : not empty
() this : not empty
() is, () not () empty () : not empty
,notempty : not empty
(),notempty : not empty
(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,) : not empty
```

Output on MSVC:

```
 :  empty
a.b. :  empty
A :  empty
() :  empty
int()(more) :  empty
(int) :  empty
foo bar :  empty
* :  empty



 :  empty
1,2 :  empty
1. :  empty
.1 :  empty
1, :  empty
(int)(float) :  empty
() this :  empty
() is, () not () empty () :  empty
,notempty :  empty
(),notempty :  empty
(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,) :  empty
```

As MSVC is completely silent, I wonder how far off my solution is. Or is it rather MSVC which is not behaving correctly?

Comment: Try to compile with /permissive :)

Comment: Try rewriting as many as you can as proper (`constexpr`) functions. Just *don't* use macros when you can avoid it (which is most of the time).

Comment: @JesperJuhl this is for C - I marked it C++ because of the applicability there, of course not because it would be recommended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft's Visual C++ preprocessor has known [compliance](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/07/06/msvc-preprocessor-progress-towards-conformance/) issues.

They have rewritten the preprocessor but the old one is enabled by default. To enable the, hopefully more compliant one select this option:

/experimental:preprocessor

Starting with the Visual Studio 2017 15.8 Preview 3 release.

I ran the macros using the option: `/experimental:preprocessor` on the latest released version 15.8.9, with the following results:

```
: empty
a.b. : not empty
A : not empty
() : not empty
int()(more) : not empty
(int) : not empty
foo bar : not empty
* : not empty


: empty
1, 2 : not empty
1. : not empty
.1 : not empty
1, : not empty
(int)(float) : not empty
() this : not empty
() is, () not () empty() : not empty
, notempty : not empty
(), notempty : not empty
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, ) : not empty
```

The erroneous "empty" is now "not empty" and is consistent with GCC and Clang' preprocessors.

Comment: Or better still; stop using macros and write functions instead (often `constexpr` ones).

Comment: @JesperJuhl  Got that right. C++ has advanced to the point where macros are rarely needed and they can introduce the most obscure bugs. Has to be a really, reallly good reason to write a macro. Save one's future self (and other users) time by avoiding them if possible.

Comment: @doug yes, but I want to use it for C also (or rather: mainly)

Comment: @Vroomfondel Yes, for C, macros have their uses and there is a large amount of legacy code, and even relatively recent embedded systems code written in C with lots of macros. I hope this helps.

Comment: @doug that what I am using it for also, it is part of a source-level cooperative "thread" scheduler (a concerted abuse of switch()). Do you have any links or names of the embedded code?

Comment: @Vroomfondel It's been quite some time when I wrestled with macros in C coding and it was all proprietary. It was actually, along with better abstraction capabilities of C++ and better compilers, that led me in the C++ direction. I used to regularly pre-process macro laden C code just to debug it. Painful.

Comment: @Vroomfondel: If you want to use C, be aware that Visual Studio supports C89 as the latest version; that's from 29 years ago (!). An outdated preprocessor is likely the least of your problems.