# Universal solution to 'ISO C99 requires at least one argument for the “…” in a variadic macro'

Tags: c-preprocessor

What is the universal way of resolving

> warning: ISO C++11 requires at least one argument for the "..." in a variadic macro

warning introduced by `-pedantic` flag for gcc?

Consider following example

```
#define FUNCTION_DECL(ret, name, ...) ret name(__VA_ARGS__)

FUNCTION_DECL(int, foo, int bar, int quax)
{
    return bar + quax;
}

FUNCTION_DECL(void, no_args)
{
}
```

Expansion of `no_args` macro [produces](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/166b8239ba6f6774) error above.

Example of solution to that would be to have two macros and then simple [overload trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761703/overloading-macro-on-number-of-arguments)

```
#define GET_MACRO(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, NAME, ...) NAME
#define METHOD_DECL2(ret, name) ret name()
#define METHOD_DECL3(ret, name, ...) ret name(__VA_ARGS__)
#define METHOD_DECL(...) GET_MACRO(__VA_ARGS__, METHOD_DECL3, METHOD_DECL3, METHOD_DECL3, METHOD_DECL3, METHOD_DECL3, METHOD_DECL3, METHOD_DECL3, METHOD_DECL2)(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Then `METHOD_DECL(void, no_args)` no longer triggers an error.

Sadly, it doesn't work in MSVC2017, but is fixed in latest preview of [MSVC2019](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/167330/-va-args-does-not-work-with-multiple-macros.html).

And this solution is somewhat clumsy. I tried to think about different solution, something like

```
#define EXTRACT_FIRST(_1, ...) _1
#define OMIT_FIRST(_1, ...) __VA_ARGS__
#define METHOD_DECL(ret, ...) ret EXTRACT_FIRST(__VA_ARGS__) OMIT_FIRST(__VA_ARGS__)
```

But this just moved the problem, since now `OMIT_FIRST` triggers this error

**EDIT:**
What I am trying to do is following:

I have function in AVR assembler (micro-controler)

```
delay_37us:
    ldi r16, 227
delay_592c_aw:
    dec r16
    brne delay_592c_aw
    nop
    nop
    ret
```

That active waits for 592cycles (which is 37us for 16MHz cpu)

In order to call this function in C, I have to mark it as `.global` and also provide C declaration of such function. In order to simplify declaration of such function I would use a macro like that

```
FUNCTION_DECL(void, delay_37us);
```

which would be defined as

```
#ifdef __ASSEMBLER__
  #define FUNCTION_DECL(ret, name, ...) .global name
#else
  #define FUNCTION_DECL(ret, name, ...) ret name(__VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```

So that I could use one header file for both C and ASM. What I am using currently is one header file with following content

```
#ifdef __ASSEMBLER__
  .global delay_37us
  .global delay_ms
  .global delay_1s
#else
  void delay_37us();
  void delay_ms(unsigned char);
  void delay_1s();
#endif
```

Which is error-prone to maintain.

Comment: I would argue that the "universal way" is to *not use macros* to begin with. What is the *actual* problem you're trying to solve my your `FUNCTION_DECL` macro?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Mixing C and assembler for AVR microcontrolers (having common header file for functions *exported* by assembler and used in C or viceversa). Something like [that](https://pastebin.com/Kau1Tb19)

Comment: Those tricks are always ugly and if you care about readability, you end up using [variadic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Example_in_C)

Comment: @KeineLust I edited my question so that the intent is clearly visible.

Comment: I think it is futile to try to cicrumvent this C++ restriction. You could look at argument counting macros (like [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53159137/what-are-the-deviations-between-preprocessors-of-gcc-clang-vs-msvc]) but I think this won't make the warning go away, as all techniques are relying on empty parameter places. This surely is a point where the standard runs against living and working enigneering practice.

Comment: The subject says ISO C99, the warning says ISO C++11, and the text itself talks about C programming. Which is it, C or C++? The empty argument list `foo()` means very different things in them. In C, you should use `foo(void)`, and in C++ you can use it. It conveniently also solves the problem for you, while technically not answering the question about variadic args.